# How to calculate sales tax with this script?

Tags: php, math, shopping-cart

I'm using a shopping cart script from a tutorial I came across a while ago, and I need to modify it to calculate sales tax for my state (Pennsylvania).  I want it to extract the state, compare it to either Pennsylvania or PA incase someone writes the state shorthand and then multiply the subtotal (for the items.. before shipping is added) by the sales tax for this state and add that to the subtotal.  How should I go about doing this?  Here is the script that does the calculation for grand total.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

/*********************************************************
*                 CHECKOUT FUNCTIONS 
*********************************************************/
function saveOrder()
{
    $orderId       = 0;
    $shippingCost  = 5;
    $requiredField = array('hidShippingFirstName', 'hidShippingLastName', 'hidShippingAddress1', 'hidShippingCity', 'hidShippingPostalCode',
                           'hidPaymentFirstName', 'hidPaymentLastName', 'hidPaymentAddress1', 'hidPaymentCity', 'hidPaymentPostalCode');

    if (checkRequiredPost($requiredField)) {
        extract($_POST);

        // make sure the first character in the 
        // customer and city name are properly upper cased
        $hidShippingFirstName = ucwords($hidShippingFirstName);
        $hidShippingLastName  = ucwords($hidShippingLastName);
        $hidPaymentFirstName  = ucwords($hidPaymentFirstName);
        $hidPaymentLastName   = ucwords($hidPaymentLastName);
        $hidShippingCity      = ucwords($hidShippingCity);
        $hidPaymentCity       = ucwords($hidPaymentCity);

        $cartContent = getCartContent();
        $numItem     = count($cartContent);

        // save order & get order id
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_order(od_date, od_last_update, od_shipping_first_name, od_shipping_last_name, od_shipping_address1, 
                                      od_shipping_address2, od_shipping_phone, od_shipping_state, od_shipping_city, od_shipping_postal_code, od_shipping_cost,
                                      od_payment_first_name, od_payment_last_name, od_payment_address1, od_payment_address2, 
                                      od_payment_phone, od_payment_state, od_payment_city, od_payment_postal_code)
                VALUES (NOW(), NOW(), '$hidShippingFirstName', '$hidShippingLastName', '$hidShippingAddress1', 
                        '$hidShippingAddress2', '$hidShippingPhone', '$hidShippingState', '$hidShippingCity', '$hidShippingPostalCode', '$shippingCost',
                        '$hidPaymentFirstName', '$hidPaymentLastName', '$hidPaymentAddress1', 
                        '$hidPaymentAddress2', '$hidPaymentPhone', '$hidPaymentState', '$hidPaymentCity', '$hidPaymentPostalCode')";
        $result = dbQuery($sql);

        // get the order id
        $orderId = dbInsertId();

        if ($orderId) {
            // save order items
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_item(od_id, pd_id, od_qty)
                        VALUES ($orderId, {$cartContent[$i]['pd_id']}, {$cartContent[$i]['ct_qty']})";
                $result = dbQuery($sql);                    
            }


            // update product stock
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
                $sql = "UPDATE tbl_product 
                        SET pd_qty = pd_qty - {$cartContent[$i]['ct_qty']}
                        WHERE pd_id = {$cartContent[$i]['pd_id']}";
                $result = dbQuery($sql);                    
            }


            // then remove the ordered items from cart
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_cart
                        WHERE ct_id = {$cartContent[$i]['ct_id']}";
                $result = dbQuery($sql);                    
            }                           
        }                   
    }

    return $orderId;
}

/*
    Get order total amount ( total purchase + shipping cost )
*/
function getOrderAmount($orderId)
{
    $orderAmount = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(pd_price * od_qty)
            FROM tbl_order_item oi, tbl_product p 
            WHERE oi.pd_id = p.pd_id and oi.od_id = $orderId

            UNION

            SELECT od_shipping_cost 
            FROM tbl_order
            WHERE od_id = $orderId";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);

    if (dbNumRows($result) == 2) {
        $row = dbFetchRow($result);
        $totalPurchase = $row[0];

        $row = dbFetchRow($result);
        $shippingCost = $row[0];

        $orderAmount = $totalPurchase + $shippingCost;
    }   

    return $orderAmount;    
}

?>
```

Comment: Edit your question and place 4 spaces before every line of code, even if it's already indented in the original. This will format it as code and preserve the original indenting. You can also use the "101\n010" button in the text editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to handle differing tax rates per municipality?  Normally this would be looked up from a tax table by zip code, and maybe even for the street address + zip code (in some states).

It would look like this:

```
// is it a Pennsylvania zip code?
if ($zipcode < 15000 || $zipcode > 19699)  // needs verification of the actual range
   $taxrate = 0;
else
{
    $rs = mysql_query ("select rate from taxtable where zipcode = '$zipcode'", $db);
    if (!$rs)
    {
        // error looking up rate, maybe apply a default?
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
        $taxrate = $row['rate'];
    }
}

$amount = $amount * (1 + $taxrate / 100.0);
```

Comment: That sounds like it would make it a lot more complicated than I'm ready to step into, but according to wikipedia:

Pennsylvania has a 6% sales tax rate. Allegheny County has a 7% sales tax rate and Philadelphia has an 8% sales tax rate.  Would it be simpler to just go with 8% so that it covers the entire range?  I don't know how I'd go about comparing every single zip code in PA.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite this code you provided to work with my script, and I'm wondering why you chose "rs" for that particular variable name.  What is it supposed to stand for?

Comment: I know it doesn't matter, and I could rename it to whatever I wanted but I'd like to understand the train of thought you're coming from..

Comment: `$rs` stands for "result" or "result set".  The examples in the PHP documents (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) use $result, but as often as I type it, I've taken to using `$rs` for brevity.

Comment: You need to beware of the pitfalls of floating point calculations on currency. SEE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144653/currency-conversion-for-e-commerce-site-preventing-incorrect-total-cart-due-to/1144757#1144757